# PHP array in class generated in function

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

I got a problem for a script I'm working on: I need the array that normaly gets generated in the query_person() function to be saved in `protected static $users` to be used across the script. This is just a quick test I made, normally the array gets generated by a query. 
The script works if I do it like this:

```
protected static $users = array('paul' => array('p_gebruikersnaam' => "paul", 'p_wachtwoord' => "de3c41cc7918c25822f1fb840a86a84b", 'p_id' => "10000000", 'p_md5' => "d1ca3aaf52b41acd68ebb3bf69079bd1")
);
```

but since the array gets generated by a db query I had to put the query in a function but it doesn't work like this then:

```
protected static $users = array();

public function query_personen(){   
$users = array('paul' => array('p_gebruikersnaam' => "paul", 'p_wachtwoord' => "de3c41cc7918c25822f140a86a84b", 'p_id' => "100000", 'p_md5' => "d1ca3aaf52b41acd68e9079bd1")
);
}
```

How do I make it work so that the second script generates the same output as the first?

Comment: Should be self::$users not $users in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function query_personen(){   
$this->users = array('paul' => array('p_gebruikersnaam' => "paul", 'p_wachtwoord' => "de3c41cc7918c25822f140a86a84b", 'p_id' => "100000", 'p_md5' => "d1ca3aaf52b41acd68e9079bd1")
);
```

You need to use `$this` to refer to the object.

If you want it to be static, you should use:

```
public static function query_personen(){   
self::$users = array('paul' => array('p_gebruikersnaam' => "paul", 'p_wachtwoord' => "de3c41cc7918c25822f140a86a84b", 'p_id' => "100000", 'p_md5' => "d1ca3aaf52b41acd68e9079bd1")
);
```

Note that the second function is a `static` function (Yours in the example isn't so you should use the first version).